# angular route deep linking using ngRoute in apache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

i have an angular js app and i am using it in a conventional html page  have included angular route also

```
           <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script> 
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.js"></script>
```

and in my module

```
 var nameApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']); 

           mainApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            console.log('config ');  
            $routeProvider

              .when('boxAuth', {
                  templateUrl: 'boxReturn.html',
                  controller: 'authController'
              });

              // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
              $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            }])

        ;
```

now if i try to access the url http://localhost:8082/boxAuth it gives 404 error

how can i deeplink to this url using angular

Comment: Have you tried `.when('/boxAuth',` ? note backslash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your server to return the index page regardless of the route so your angular application loads

if you cannot do that consider using hash(#) routing

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you forget to add    `<base href="/" />` to your index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular Demo</title>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <base href="/" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllersTest.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/boxAuth', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/boxReturn.html',
                controller: 'authController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/boxAuth'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

And finally you nedd to add .htaccess file  inside your root folder and paste this

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar app, and this code is working for me. Hope it helps you!

var module = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);

```
            module.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider.
                when('/abc', {
                    templateUrl: 'abc.jsp',
                    controller: 'MyController'
                }).
                when('/xyz.jsp', {
                    templeateUrl: '/Test1/xyz.jsp',
                    controller: 'LoginController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: ''
                });
            }]);
```

Comment: Also the html looks something like this:

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#abc">abc</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="xyz.jsp">xyz</a></li>
   </ul>